# .NET SVM for regression

Tags: .net, regression, svm

I'm looking for a Support Vector Machine library that I can use in my .NET projects.  The two promising ones I've found so far are [NPatternRecognizer](http://npatternrecognizer.codeplex.com/), but it only supports classification (not regression).  [LibSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) supports regression, but the .NET wrappers don't seem to.  Are there any good recommendations for .NET SVM libraries that support regression?

Comment: http://www.matthewajohnson.org/software/svm.html claims to be a clean conversion of libsvm 2.89... some investigation needs to be done to see if this includes regression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SVM.NET](http://www.matthewajohnson.org/software/svm.html) looks like it supports regression.